# OMNET++: Class not Found --perhaps code is not linked or the class was not registered

Tags: c++, omnet++

I am trying to use other modules that are defined in another project (NED and C++). That's the error I got

[image: error Screenshot]

NED is linked correctly, but my project can not access the c++  (datarateSpectrum) files of the other project.

The steps I went through trying to solve this issue are as follow:

- I made sure to include define_module()
- I edited the basic project makemake to produce a shared library and my project makemake to be linked with external sources.
- I am able to see that my project is able to access the other project library however I still get the same error message.

Any help is much much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Are you able to run the project containing `datarateSpectrum` standalone without error? Do you use namespaces?

Comment: yes, I am able to run the project containing datarateSpectrum standalone. I managed to sort this out by copying all the CC files manually to my extended project, I do not feel it is the best way though to do the linking.

Answer (score -1):

This error can happen when some functions are defined in datarateSpectrum.h but not implemented in datarateSpectrum.cc.