# C++ class not found when running OMNET++ project

Tags: c++, omnet++, inet

Please someone could help me to fix my issue? I will be very grateful.

I try to implement LEACH PROTOCOL. So I added a simple module named Leach to the INET compound module SensorNode. Now I'm implementing my protocol in C++ by creating the Leach.h and Leach.cc files. My Leach class is well registered with OMNET++ via the command Define_Module(Leach); but when running the project, I got the error as it appears on this image on the link:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tji1.png

Here is the inside of my sensor node with the position of my Leach simple module: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQQk3.png

Similar questions are asked here [OMNET++: Class not Found --perhaps code is not linked or the class was not registered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43614698/omnet-class-not-found-perhaps-code-is-not-linked-or-the-class-was-not-regis)
But what they advise doesn't sort out my concern.

Please looking forward to your input.

I'm using OMNET++6.0preview10 with INET 4.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) make sure that your new code is **inside** the `src` folder. Anything outside of the `src` folder is NOT compiled and linked.
b) if you are building from the command line, re-run `make makefiles` after adding any new .cc files

Comment: Thanks @Rudi for yor input. Only the C++ files will be inside the src folder?

Comment: By convention also the NED folder is set to the src folder so NED files are also there. Most projects also set an additional NED folder for example networks and INI files (but in that folder .cc fileas are not allowed)